# How to handle store procedure exception message to entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, throw

How to catch the RAISEERROR or SQL 2012 - THROW exception from sql store procedure to entity framework - store procedure call ?

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
{
        IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> empDetails  =  context. Database.SqlQuery
                                                                      < EmployeeDetails >("exec GetEmployeeData ", null).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try / Catch?

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> empDetails  =  context. Database.SqlQuery                                                            <EmployeeDetails>("exec GetEmployeeData ", null).ToList();
    }
    Catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I am observing that `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` doesn't throw any Exception originated from the Stored Procedure as `RAISEERROR` and `THROW` Any thing you can help on this?

Comment: My first thought is because of async.  But comments are not the correct place for this.  You should post a new question with code examples.